# GCP marketplace - service provider subscription permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform

What is the permission required to register to a service provider in GCP marketplace? (attached image below for context)

I am trying to subscribe to a service provider on google cloud marketplace, but am getting a permission error when attempting to register. The UI is supplying a general error, without specifying the required permissions. Same when looking in devtools  - the 403 get response for:  `https://console.cloud.google.com/m/marketplace/procurement/jwt?purpose=SIGNUP...` does not provide any useful information, just a "backend error" message. Tried searching their [list of permissions reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) but could not find anything related to "marketplace", "signup" or "procurement".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found the required permissions - you should have a billing admin role in the billing account you are using to register to the marketplace service.